# Stuck on counting highest occurence of DNF

Tags: c, arrays, struct

so I am trying to count who had the most DNF in four bicycle races.
I have only accomplished to filter and print the riders who did not finish. 
But as I am relatively new to arrays I am having trouble programming the logic which can:

print only the rider who had the most DNF in the four races.

this my loop for returning all DNF riders so some names is duplicated:

```
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < 790; i++){
    if(strcmp(results[i].rider_placement, "DNF") == 0) {
      printf(" %-40s \n",
      results[i].rider_name);
    }
  }
```

I know that this might not be enough information, but anything to help my thinking right now will be appreciated.

edit: To clarify DNF is riders who retired from a race

This is the struct used to store data from a txt file:

ex. ParisRoubaix  "Greg VAN AVERMAET" 32  BMC   BEL  1  5:41:07

ex. ParisRoubaix  "Sam BEWLEY"  30  ORS  NZL  DNF  0

```
struct result_t {
char stage_name[STAGE_LEN];
char rider_name[NAME_LEN];
int  rider_age;
char rider_team[TEAM_LEN];
char rider_nation[NATION_LEN];
char rider_placement[NATION_LEN];
char time[TIME_LEN];
};
```

Comment: what is DNF? How is it stored?

Comment: Can you post the definition of a `results` struct?

Comment: I have updated my post

Comment: @LG94.: Provide what are your data and what you need to know...give an example...atleast show one record data

Comment: @LG94.: Ok now given those data - what you want to have? Explain one output

Comment: @coderredoc
I only want to print the rider with the highest amount of DNF's, like this:

"Sam Bewley"

Comment: @LG94.: But you did that already why ask the question?

Comment: @coderredoc
 the ouput i have now is like: 
"Sam BEWLEY" 

"Luke DURBRIDGE"

"xxx" etc. 

I want to count the amount of DNF for each rider and only output the rider(s)  with highest amount of DNF.

Comment: @LG94.: Well one thing - how do you know how many DNF a player has? The `struct` you declared - which member of it denotes that?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a counter to your structur like?

```
struct result_t {
    char stage_name[STAGE_LEN];
    .
    .
    int counter = 0;
}
```

And whenever this person receives a DNF, just like in your provided loop

```
for(i = 0; i < 790; i++){
    if(strcmp(results[i].rider_placement, "DNF") == 0) {
        printf(" %-40s \n",
        results[i].rider_name);
        results[i].counter += 1;  //<-- pref. impl counter
    }
}
```

you count it up and after your math is done, you compare all the counters
so see who's got the highest..?